# Generate multiple Razor Pages css isolation bundles

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-core-7.0

Razor Pages has a [bundling feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#css-isolation) for use with css isolation.

I have these pages:

- `/Pages/Products/Index.cshtml.css`
- `/Pages/Orders/Edit.cshtml.css`
- `/Pages/Orders/Create.cshtml.css`

During compilation, a bundle will be generated: `~/AssemblyName.styles.css`.

However, suppose I also have private pages only for staff members:

- `/Pages/Private/Accounts.cshtml.css`
- `/Pages/Private/Administration.cshtml.css`
- `/Pages/Private/Dashboard.cshtml.css`

They would be included in the same bundle as above.

How can I generate two bundles: one for users, and another for staff?

**UPDATE**
I'm aware of tools for compiling / minifying / bundling, but prefer a built-in approach *if possible*.

Answer (score 1):

> ASP.NET Core is compatible with WebOptimizer, an open-source bundling
> and minification solution. For set up instructions and sample
> projects, see WebOptimizer. ASP.NET Core doesn't provide a native
> bundling and minification solution.

Bundling is the process of taking  multiple source files and combining them into a single output file. We can  create one for users.
like:

```
builder.Services.AddWebOptimizer(pipeline =>
{
    pipeline.AddCssBundle("/css/bundle.css", "css/a.css", "css/b.css");
});
```

When using bundling, we have to update our  and  tags to point to the bundle route. It could look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bundle.css" />
```

You can have a look at [Bundle and minify static assets in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-7.0)  and [Bundling](https://github.com/ligershark/WebOptimizer?tab=readme-ov-file#bundling) to know more.

Comment: +1 Thanks! I was hoping there is a way to do it without extra tools (especially since all the compiling / minification / bundling tools for .net are out of date or maintained by just one person). I do appreciate this answer though, it is helpful. Do you know whether there is a built-in way to emit multiple bundles without extra tools?

Comment: Hi @lonix , you are welcome:)  Judging from the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-8.0#choose-a-bundling-and-minification-strategy), there is no such built-in solution. You can go to GitHub to submit a new feature request.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is this is not currently possible.

##### I added a [feature request](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/52927), please upvote it if you need this functionality.

The other answer shows a workaround using a separate tool (WebOptimizer). It is not actively maintained, so beware (see the repo's issues to understand the problem). There are other tools as well, such as Smidge. All such tools are out of date, or maintained by just one core contributor - I think that's too risky for a production system.

What I'm doing currently is manually concatenating the files as an msbuild task.